# Ruby: dynamically generate attribute_accessor

Tags: ruby, attr-accessor

I'm trying to generate the attr_reader from a hash (with nested hash) so that it mirror the instance_variable creation automatically.

here is what i have so far:

```
data = {:@datetime => '2011-11-23', :@duration => '90', :@class => {:@price => '£7', :@level => 'all'}}


class Event
 #attr_reader :datetime, :duration, :class, :price, :level
  def init(data, recursion)
   data.each do |name, value|
    if value.is_a? Hash
      init(value, recursion+1)
    else
      instance_variable_set(name, value)
      #bit missing: attr_accessor name.to_sym 
    end
  end
end
```

But i can't find out a way to do that :(

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You need to call the (private) class method `attr_accessor` on the `Event` class:

```
    self.class.send(:attr_accessor, name)
```

I recommend you add the `@` on this line:

```
    instance_variable_set("@#{name}", value)
```

And don't use them in the hash.

```
    data = {:datetime => '2011-11-23', :duration => '90', :class => {:price => '£7', :level => 'all'}}
```

Comment: You ARE my new best friend!!!! that just work and is so simple... Ruby is magic :) and YOU are a star :) (I'm happy because I looked for a while)

Comment: Just a quick question more, is there any way to prepend the name of the containing hash to the accessor name, so that i could call my_class.class.price, or something like that?

Comment: First of all, 'class' is a reserved keyword, don't use it. Your second question in your comment here goes beyond the scope of this particular question. You might want to start a new question, since it deals with recursion and such, not with attribute accessors. (PS, don't forget to accept the best answer)

Comment: It's worth noting that because you're acting on the class, any future instances of the class will also have your attribute accessors that have previously been defined dynamically.

Comment: @MikeCampbell Is it possible to do this on an object instance. Specifically i am trying to conditionally add attributes in an included parent class.

Answer (score 5):

You could do a bit of meta-magic to solve this, using method_missing:

```
class Event
  def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
    if instance_variable_names.include? "@#{method_name}"
      instance_variable_get "@#{method_name}"
    else
      super
    end
  end
end
```

What this will do is allow access to object instance variables via object.variable syntax, if the object has those variables defined, without resorting to modifying the entire class via attr_accessor.

Answer (score 3):

`attr_accessor` is a class method and as such needs to be invoked on the class. It is also a private method, so you need to invoke it in a context in which the class object is `self`.

As an example:

```
class C
  def foo
    self.class.instance_eval do
      attr_accessor :baz
    end
  end
end
```

After creating an instance of `C` and calling `foo` on that instance, that instance -- and all future instances -- will contain methods `baz` and `baz=`.